# Meteor does not display collection that exists in db

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs, meteor-react, react-dom

A Meteor/React noob here, going through the [Meteor-React tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app) and got stuck on step 3. My problem is that the data is not being displayed in the browser, although it exists in the db.

**Here is my imports/ui/App.jsx:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js';

import Task from './Task.jsx';

class App extends Component {
  renderTasks() {
    return this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
      <Task key={task._id} task={task} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Todo List</h1>
        </header>

        <ul>
          {this.renderTasks()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  tasks: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  return {
    tasks: Tasks.find({}).fetch(),
  };
}, App);
```

No errors show up in console.

Basically `this.props.tasks` returns empty array. But `db.tasks.find({})` in console shows records. Without changing much around, if I hardcode Tasks records, they display alright, so the issue isn't with Task component. Anyone can help here? Would much appreciate.

**client/main.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from '../imports/ui/App.jsx';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('render-target'));
});
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "simple-todos",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0"
  }
}
```

**npm version `3.3.12`
node version `5.6.0`**

Comment: just to cross check, please check your console to see whether you have any `import` issues & also before returning in `renderTasks()`, console log your data to see if it's passing proper data or not.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Thanks for the suggestion. `console.log(Tasks.find({}).fetch());` before `renderTasks()` also returns `[]`

Comment: Also, no errors in console

Comment: can you try a constructor within your App class like this? `constructor(props){super(props);}; `

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I put your constructor function before `renderTasks()`, no change.

Comment: your code is almost identical to my version i tried out. so i'm also getting confused.

Comment: Interesting that if I add `Tasks.insert({text: "Hello, world!"});` after `import` statements, I can see the task flashing for a second before getting re-rendered. Then it disappears.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112857/discussion-between-faysal-ahmed-and-petr-gazarov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of your description from, it seems that your database is not accessible on both server & client. May be you forgot to add the reference of your database in the server side. try to import your tasks `main.js` file of your server.

Make sure your server/main.js has the following line:

```
import '../imports/api/tasks.js';
```